# click() working for some buttons and not others

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

I have these buttons:

```
<button class="btn" id="empty">Empty Cart</button>
<button class="btn" id="submit">Add to Cart</button>
```

And this in a $(document).ready block in the head:

```
$("#empty").click(function() {
   alert("I give up");
});
$("#submit").click(function() {
   // ...
});
```

Why does #submit work and #empty does not?

Comment: if is  a dynamically created element use like this `$(document).on('click','#empty',function(){ //do })`

Comment: paste entire html and javascript code

Comment: I copied your code to a JSFiddle and it works fine https://jsfiddle.net/qscpuect/  ?

Comment: Your code seems to be working, there must some other issue. Do you get any console errors?

Comment: Also never give any form element the name or ID of "submit" -  it hides the form's submit event handler

Comment: Some guesses. 1) if those buttons are in a form, both of them submit the data, since both are submit buttons. The top one should have been `type="reset"` instead. 2) Maybe you have errors such as multiple IDs. The Javascript code as given works only on the first element with a given ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there are no problems here! I put it in this code snippet. So if any other problem is here notice me.

```js
$("#empty").click(function() {
   alert("I give up");
});
$("#submit").click(function() {
    alert("I am submit");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn" id="empty">Empty Cart</button>
<button class="btn" id="submit">Add to Cart</button>
```

The main reason may prevent to call `click` is with dynamic elements. In this case, you should use:

```
$(document).on('click', '#empty', function() {
   alert("I give up");
});
```

Comment: This was the case.  Thank you so much!  I didn't even consider that this could be relevant.